# No se me guarda los valores de los objetos cuando los paso a otras clases (Editado)

Tags: poo, objeto

Buen dia miembro de la comunidad. Primeramente soy un novato en java, entonces poniendome a prueba queria hacer una Galeria de Fotos con javafx y SceneBuilder. Bueno, en la interfaz grafica si puedo defenderme (refiriendome que ahi ya puedo investigar un poco de mi parte), pero tengo problemas en las clases modelos.
El objetivo de este proyecto, de la galeria, es guardar fotos en albumes, bueno es obvio jeje, pero estoy usando listas. Estoy usando 2 listas, especificamente listas circulares doblemente enlazadas, una lista como decir la de mas alto nivel (llamemosle listaHome)son los que tienen como en la parte del contenido de cada nodo un album, y ese album actua como otra lista (llamemosle listaAlbum), donde el contenido de cada uno de sus nodos son fotos, fotos que como yo lo veo, son instancias de una clase Foto con sus atributos: nombre, lugar, fecha etc. Las dos clases que hice que actuan como lista las hice clases genericas

*****************Tal como dice el titulo, se me ocurrio de otra forma, la que si veo mas conveniente y que debe funcionar, pero el probkema sigue persistiendo, no se me guardan los valores. De igual manera, dejo la primera publicacion que realice, y el modificado que mencione, como una respuesta a esta publicacion--------------------------

Entonces lo que se me ocurrio para crear una foto que perteneza a un album y se guarde en la listaHome es, creo un objeto tipo foto, la guardo dentro de un album, mediante un metodo add() que realice, como decir:

```
 Foto foto = new Foto(atributos para el constructor);
 listaAlbum<Foto1> primerAlbum = new listaAlbum<>();
 primerAlbum.add(foto);
```

Pero el problema viene cuando quiero guardar esa listaAlbum con un nodo con contenido una foto, como un nodo de la listaHome. De igual manera cree un metodo add() en la clase listaHome.

```
    listaHome<Album> listah1 = new listaHome<>();
    listah1.add(primerAlbum);
```

Pero cuando llamo a

```
    listah1.getContenido().getContenido();
//con el primer getcontenido recupero un album, con el segundo getContenido, recuperaria la 
foto del album que recupere previamente, pero me bota como que no tengo nada, es decir un null
```

Adjunto un poco de codigo, espero que lo entendais, como dije soy un novao en java. Pienso por ahora de manera primitiva

```
    public class listaHome<E> implements List<E>{
       private Album<Foto> firstAlbumFoto;
       private Album<Foto> lastAlbumFoto;


        public Album<E> getSiguiente() {
            return siguienteAlbum;
        }

        public void setSiguiente(Album<E> siguiente) {
            this.siguienteAlbum = siguiente;
        }

        public Album<E> getAnterior() {
            return anteriorAlbum;
        }

        public void setAnterior(Album<E> anterior) {
            this.anteriorAlbum = anterior;
        }

         public boolean addFirst(E e) {
                listaAlbum<Foto> albumT = (listaAlbum) e;
                String nombre = albumT.getNameAlbum();
                listaAlbum<Foto> albumN = new listaAlbum<>(nombre);
                if(this.isEmpty()){
                    this.firstAlbumFoto = albumN;
                    albumN.setSiguiente(this.firstAlbumFoto);
                    albumN.setAnterior(this.firstAlbumFoto);     
                }else{
                    Album<Foto1> temporal = this.firstAlbumFoto;
                    while(temporal.getSiguiente() != this.firstAlbumFoto){
                        temporal = temporal.getSiguiente();
                    }
                    temporal.setSiguiente(albumN);
                    albumN.setAnterior(temporal);
                    albumN.setSiguiente(this.firstAlbumFoto);
                    this.firstAlbumFoto.setAnterior(albumN);
                    this.firstAlbumFoto = albumN;
                   }
                 return true;
                 }
            }

    public listaAlbum<T> implements List<E>{
       private Foto primeroFoto;
       private Foto ultimoFoto;
       private Album<E> siguienteAlbum;
       private Album<E> anteriorAlbum;

        public Foto getPrimeroFoto() {
            return primeroFoto;
        }

        public void setPrimeroFoto(Foto primero) {
            this.primeroFoto = primero;
        }

        public Foto getUltimoFoto() {
            return ultimoFoto;
        }

        public void setUltimoFoto(Foto ultimo) {
            this.ultimoFoto = ultimo;
        }

         public boolean addFirst(E e) {
              if(e == null){
                return false;
              }
              Foto1 foto = (Foto1) e;
              String nombre = foto.getContenido();
              Foto1 nuevo = new Foto1(nombre);

              if(this.isEmpty()){
                this.primeroFotoAlbum = nuevo;
                nuevo.setSiguiente(this.primeroFotoAlbum);
                nuevo.setAnterior(this.primeroFotoAlbum);
              }else{
                Foto1 temporal = this.primeroFotoAlbum;
                while(temporal.getSiguiente() != this.primeroFotoAlbum){
                    temporal = temporal.getSiguiente();
                }
                temporal.setSiguiente(nuevo);
                nuevo.setAnterior(temporal);
                nuevo.setSiguiente(this.primeroFotoAlbum);
                this.primeroFotoAlbum.setAnterior(nuevo);
                this.primeroFotoAlbum = nuevo;
              }
    
             return true;
         }
    }

    public class Foto{

        private Foto siguiente;
        private Foto anterior;
        private String contenido;

        public Foto(String contenido){
            this.contenido = contenido;
        }
    }
```

Me olvide mencionar que las clases que actuan como lista implementan una interface List, el cual su estructura es esta.

```
    public interface List<E> {
        public boolean addFirst(E e); // inserta el elemento e al inicio

        public boolean addLast(E e); // inserta el elemento e al final

        public E removeFirst(); // remueve el elemento al inicio de la lista

        public E removeLast(); // remueve el elemento al final de la lista

        public int size();

        public boolean isEmpty();

        public void clear();          

        public void add(int index, E element); // inserta element en la posición index

        public E remove(int index); // remueve y retorna el elemento en la posición index

        public E get(int index); // retorna el elemento ubicado en la posición index

        public E set(int index, E element); // setea el element en la posición index

        public String toString(); // retorna una cadena de caracteres                                 representando los elementos que la lista contiene*/

    }
```

Entonces como dije al principio, veo como que cuando voy a guardar como nodo en listaHome el nodo album que ya contiene una foto me devuelve resultado como que estoy guardando un album vacio, mas no ninguna foto

Actualizacion

****************Esta es la modificacion que he pensado. Primero me base en la estructura de una lista. Bueno, una lista doblemente enlazada, donde una clase actua como la propia lista y otra clase como el contenido de sus nodos. Por ende como pense en dos listas:

1.La listaHome se representara por dos clases, la que actuara como lista y
la otra como nodo, llamemosle listaHome y listaHomeNodo respectivamente

2.De igual manera que la listaHome, la listaAlbum se representara por dos
clases: listaAlbum y listaAlbumNodo respectivamente. Y el contenido de
cada nodo de estos ser una fotografia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando pongo mas de una foto en el album, es como que se reseteara los valores

```
    public boolean addFirst(E e) {
    System.out.println("myinstancia es de tipo " +  ((Object)e).getClass().getSimpleName());
    if(e == null){
        return false;
    }
        LCDENodo<E> albumN = new LCDENodo<>(e);
        
        if(this.isEmpty()){
            albumN.setSiguiente(this.firstAlbum);
            albumN.setAnterior(this.firstAlbum);     
        }else{
            LCDENodo<E> temporal = this.firstAlbum;
            while(temporal.getSiguiente() != this.firstAlbum){
                temporal = temporal.getSiguiente();
            }
            temporal.setSiguiente(albumN);
            albumN.setAnterior(temporal);
            albumN.setSiguiente(this.firstAlbum);
            this.firstAlbum.setAnterior(albumN);
            this.firstAlbum = albumN;
        }
    }   
        return true;
    }
```

Pero no se me guardan las fotos

Comment: javafx ya tiene una interface para listas `ObservableList` e implementarla es sencillo con metodos que devuelven objetos que implementan dicha interfaz `FXCollections.observableList<e>()` . no veo razón para reinventar la rueda